# Is it possible to force a reload of a thread_local variable after migration across kernel threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, g++

I am implementing user threading on top of kernel and threads and observed that, when a user thread migrates between kernel threads, `thread_local` variables are read from the previous kernel location even when the variables are also tagged as `volatile`.

Since the compiler merely sees a user-level `swapcontext` as a function call, the example below demonstrates the problem with a simple function call.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

__thread Foo* volatile foo;

void bar() {
    asm("nop");
}
void f() {
    foo->x = 5;
    bar();
    asm volatile("":::"memory");
    // We desire a second computation of the address of foo here as an offset
    // from the FS register.
    foo->y = 7;
}

int main(){
    foo = new Foo;
    f();
    delete foo;
}
```

Next we run the following commands to compile and disassemble. Note that the `-fPIC` flag seems necessary to reproduce this problem, and is also required for my use case because I am building a library. Assume the code above is in a file called `TL.cc`

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3  -fPIC  -Wall -g TL.cc   -o TL 
objdump -d TL
```

Here is the assembly dump for the function `f()`.

```
  400760:       53                      push   %rbx
  # Notice this computation happens only once.
  400761:       64 48 8b 04 25 00 00    mov    %fs:0x0,%rax
  400768:       00 00 
  40076a:       48 8d 80 f8 ff ff ff    lea    -0x8(%rax),%rax
  400771:       48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
  400774:       48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  400777:       c7 00 05 00 00 00       movl   $0x5,(%rax)
  40077d:       e8 ce ff ff ff          callq  400750 <_Z3barv>
  # Observe that the value of rbx came from before the function call,
  # so if the function bar() actually returned on a different kernel
  # thread, we would be referencing the original kernel thread's 
  # version of foo, instead of the new kernel thread's version.
  400782:       48 8b 03                mov    (%rbx),%rax
  400785:       c7 40 04 07 00 00 00    movl   $0x7,0x4(%rax)
  40078c:       5b                      pop    %rbx
  40078d:       c3                      retq   
  40078e:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

We observe the register `rax` is being reloaded from memory, but that the memory location was determined before the call to `bar()`.

**Is there a way to force a reload of the address of the variable as an offset from the current value of the `fs` register?**

I am fine with using gcc-specific hacks if those exist.

Here is the output `g++ --version`

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Does a simple `asm volatile("":::"memory");` do the trick for you?

Comment: Nope,  it doesn't force a recomputation of the address of the TLS variable,  so it is still using the old address even though it is accessing memory and not a value cached in a register.

Comment: Can you post the relevant source code?

Comment: Not concisely in a way that would compile and link, although conceptually it's nothing more than what the asm already shows; a computation of the address of a TLS value followed by repeated usage. The source would just show two accesses to a thread local variable,  one before and one after the thread context,  and doesn't make the problem clear.

Comment: I'm confused.  When I do this:  `__thread int foo; void f() { printf("%i\n", foo); asm volatile("":::"memory"); printf("%i\n", foo); }`, I see `foo` being loaded relative to `%fs` twice.  Isn't that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @tmyklebu, Your simple example behaves correctly, but this technique does not appear to generalize to more complex code; I attempted to use `asm volatile("":::"memory");` after a `swapcontext` and it did not cause the desired re-computation of a TLS variable as an offset from the `FS` register.

Comment: @merlin2011: OK, can you post an example that breaks or do you just want us to guess?  I apparently haven't successfully guessed what the C++ code resulting in your assembly dump looks like.

Comment: @tmyklebu, Turns out that I could not reproduce it without `-fPIC`. Please see the updated example.

Comment: OK, interesting!  I can reproduce on gcc-6.3.0.

Comment: I filed gcc bug [80258](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80258) with a test case that breaks.

Comment: @tmyklebu, Thanks for filing this. It looks like after [11 long years](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26461), Andrew Pinski still does not believe in user threading. I guess I'll have to build a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following hack which forces a reload of the TLS in all the cases that I tested, but would appreciate feedback on all the ways it may be broken.

```
#define SafeTLS(TypeName, name) \
struct name##_SafeClass { \
    name##_SafeClass& \
    __attribute__ ((noinline)) \
    operator=(const TypeName& other) { \
        asm (""); \
        name = const_cast<TypeName&>(other); \
        return *this; \
    } \
    TypeName& \
    __attribute__ ((noinline)) \
    operator->() { \
       asm (""); \
        return get(); \
    } \
    operator TypeName() { return get(); } \
    TypeName& \
    __attribute__ ((noinline)) \
    get() { \
        asm (""); \
        return name; \
    } \
   \
    TypeName* \
    operator&() { \
        asm (""); \
        return &name; \
    } \
} name##_Safe
```

Here is a more sophisticated test case that uses this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TLS.h"

struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

__thread Foo* volatile foo;
__thread int bar;

SafeTLS(Foo* volatile, foo);
SafeTLS(int, bar);

void f2() {
    asm("nop");
}
void f() {
    foo_Safe->x = 5;
    f2();
    asm volatile("":::"memory");
    // We desire a second computation of the address of foo here as an offset
    // from the FS register.
    (*foo_Safe).y = 7;
    bar = 7;
    printf("%d\n", bar);
    printf("%d %d\n", foo->x, foo->y);

    bar = 8;
    printf("%d\n", bar_Safe.get());
}

int main(){
    foo = new Foo;
    f();
    delete foo;
}
```